Logistic regression with gradient descent derivation
Our maximum likelihood is:
$$l(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y\log(p(x))+(1-y)\log(1-p(x))$$
$$l(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y^{(i)} \log(\sigma(\beta^\intercal x^{(i)})) + (1 - y^{(i)}) \log(1 - \sigma(\beta^\intercal x^{(i)}))
$$
$$l(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y^{(i)} \log\left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)})}}\right) + (1 - y^{(i)}) \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)})}}\right)
$$
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial l(\beta_0)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left[ y^{(i)} \frac{1}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)}}} e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)}} \frac{1}{(1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)}})^2} - (1 - y^{(i)}) \frac{1}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)}}} e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)}} \frac{1}{(1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{(i)}})^2} \right]$$
am I good so far? I want to reach the forms:
$$\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \theta_j} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left( \sigma(\theta^\intercal x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)} \right) x_j^{(i)}
$$
